# how to add data to array using for loop in php?

Tags: php, database, arrays, for-loop

I am making a mysql query . I want to add  result to an array. suppose I am selecting all user from user table. I want to get everyones name. if the row=5 i want to save every name according to the row index.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  
    {  
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        //echo ($row);
         $num=mysql_num_rows($query);
        echo ($num);
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num;$i++){

        //here I want to save all name to an array.              

        }
```

Please help.

Comment: read any basic PHP MySQL tutorial on the web. This is pretty basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
$rows = array();
// while there are more records, add them to `$rows`
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows []= $row;
}
```

Note that [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) will just return false if there are no (more) records in the result set. So you don't need the call to `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    {
        $names[] = $row['name'];
    }
}
```

That will create an array called `$names` which you can loop through later. Also, it's a good time to look into mysqli_* functions, or PDO.